# What's the $S_n$ invaraint projection from $\mathbb{C}S_n$ to $\mathbb{C}S_nc_{\lambda}$?

Tags: representation-theory

As complex vector spaces, there is a $S_n$ invaraint projection $\pi:\mathbb{C}S_n\to \mathbb{C}S_nc_{\lambda}$, I wonder how this projection is obtained ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $c_\lambda^2=\alpha c_\lambda$ for some scalar $\alpha$, where $c_\lambda$ is the Young symmetrizer. Therefore $c_\lambda/\alpha$ is an idempotent, and the projection $\pi:\mathbb{C}S_n\to\mathbb{C}S_nc_\lambda$ is the right-multiplication-by-$c_\lambda/\alpha$ map given by the formula $\pi(x)=xc_\lambda/\alpha$, which is $S_n$-equivariant since

$$ \pi(\sigma x)=(\sigma x)c_\lambda/\alpha=\sigma(xc_\lambda/\alpha)=\sigma\pi(x) $$

for all $\sigma\in S_n$ and $x\in\mathbb{C}S_n$.

Comment: But I read that this projection is right-multiplication by $x\in\mathbb{C}[Sn]$, with $x=xx$, if it's just $c_{\lambda}$, why do people use $x$?

Comment: The projection you said is not $S_n$-invariant.

Comment: @Danny The map $\pi(x)=xc_\lambda$ satisfies $\pi(\sigma x)=(\sigma x)c_\lambda=\sigma(xc_\lambda)=\sigma\pi(x)$ for all $\sigma\in S_n$ and $x\in\mathbb{C}S_n$, so it is $S_n$-equivariant (not "invariant"). I have no idea what you're talking about in your first comment.

Comment: Thank you, for the first comment, can you take a look of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992431/lemma-4-25-of-fultons-book.

Comment: But $c_{\lambda}c_{\lambda}\ne c_{\lambda}$, by the definition, the projection should have $c_{\lambda}c_{\lambda}= c_{\lambda}$.

Comment: @Danny That's a good point. That can be fixed by normalizing $c_\lambda$. I've edited.

Comment: Thanks I don't feel confused now.